# flutter animation listener is not working when device is locked

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, background

I am using flutter animation. running animation and I repeated my animation using status listeners. but the animation status listener is not working when I lock my screen or go home. the animation stop working. simply my animation is not working in the background.

Thank You.

Comment: why would you want to animate anything when screen is locked or app is not visible in any othre way?

Comment: I am running a stopwatch timer using animation. so I want it to be run in the background also.

Comment: just save the timestamp when you start the stopwatch and when your app runs back in the foreground use this value to show the stopwatch again

Comment: for example you started stopwatch at 8:20 for 5 hours, quit the app and run it again at 10:20, so it is pretty easy to calculate what value you should start with...